# Загрузка файла на сайт с выводом инпута

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

Идет форма, которая выводится на PHP. В ней есть инпут (name="file"), при нажатии на который, или при нажатии кнопки обзор, рядом с ним, идет выбор файла. Вот охота, чтобы после выбора файла, имя ему присваивалось автоматом, при этом если такой файл уже существует, имя бы присваивалось другое, и без перезагрузки возвращался инпут следующего содержания:

```
<input type="text" name="file" value="folder/target/имя_файла.***" readonly="true">
```

Прошу подсказать, как это можно сделать.

Comment: начни с чтения про input type="file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загружаете файл на сервере без перегрузки страницы с помощью [этого](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), например, инструмента. Инструмент содержит в себе серверную часть на PHP, в ней же уже сохраняете файл с приемлемым именем и возвращаете его (при установке инструмента на клиентскую часть есть возможность отслеживать событие завершения загрузки файла, в которое передаётся ответ сервера).